# Value Adding VS Non Value Adding - Technique to identify.

Tags: business-analyst, process-engineering, process-improvement, business-case, business-improvement

[image]

For this question how would I go about identifying the non value adding?

In my opinion non value adding would be activities with a wait and huge delay = 2,3,5,6,9 and 10

On a side note, would any of these be business value adding? Can someone please provide formal definitions for each and a process they would use to identify and sort processes.

Please justify and correct my responses.

Answer (score 5):

**If you reduce or remove a non value adding activity the overall outcome won't change, but the process time will be reduced.** Often the non value adding activities take some time, but they can be caused by unnecessary transportation, doing things again etc. In Lean production they are called **[waste](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/08/waste-in-software-development/)**. A couple of examples:

- corrections: when you have to fix things
- over-production: when you do more than you need
- over-processing: when something can be done in a simpler way
- transportation: when you move stuff around unnecessarily
- motion: when you have to move around unnecessarily
- inventory: when you have to store something
- waiting: when you have to wait for somebody or something

These are all non value adding activities.

For example, if you have a doctors appointment, when you wait for it, it is a non value adding activity from your point of view. Another example, if you have a small kitchen and you have to move stuff around all the time to be able to make breakfast, that is also a non value adding activity, however it has nothing to do with time; it is a *transportation waste*.

I think your example is some kind of an exercise and I don't want to solve it instead of you, but when something *sits* or *waits* is a waste.

Comment: Wow that helped so much!

What about stuff like authorization? The business still needs to do it...

Comment: Authorization can be wasteful. From your point of view, when you are waiting for it happening it is a waste. 

When it happens, it can have all kinds of waste too. For example over-processing, when they check something that they have checked, or when they decline something because they didn't told you about it. Waste is always from a certain point of view. When you are waiting for authorization, you see waste, but that time is not waste for those who are doing it.

Comment: To help remember what Zsolt laid out, use the acronym Tim Wood.  Transportation, Inventory, Motion, Waste, Over-production, Over-processing, Defects.